# Cannot connect to a specific website on my laptop or on my smartphone using Chrome

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, google-chrome, router

All of a sudden I can't use https://laracasts.com/ anymore.

I was updating my AMD video driver when suddenly I couldn't connect to this specific website anymore, I get **ERR_CONNECTION_RESET** sometimes, I get **ERR_TIMED_OUT** sometimes, I tried:

- Reset the TCP/IP stack.
- Release the IP address.
- Renew the IP address.
- Flush and reset the DNS client resolver cache.

On my phone in the same network, get the same errors for the same website as well.
Also tried using Internet Explorer to view the website, also not good.
Nothing is working, I'm not really sure what happened so If you have any idea please help me.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

If this is on your own network, connect directly to your router or even better your modem using an Ethernet cable. See if you can reach the site. If unable to reach it, check your network adapter properties for anything that looks out of the ordinary. If you can, download CCleaner, and Malwarebytes programs. They are free and may clean up your files and search for malware your antivirus may miss. Also flush your browser's cache and disable add-ons until you get this resolved. Let me know if this helped. Otherwise, your router or modem seems suspect. I use CCleaner as well as Malwarebytes and find them to be good tools.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Comment: @MikeM Yeah I tried that like 3 times but its not working I don't know really, maybe its down in my region?